# Animate image on scroll

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-waypoints

I'm wanting to cycle through the frames of an image on scroll to give the effect of an object spinning clockwise as you scroll down the page, then anticlockwise as you scroll up. I've looked at [Jquery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/) plugin as a possible way of doing this but wondered if anyone knew of a cleaner way of doing this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I made a quick script which shows the current scroll position in percent.
I think it's a good base to start working from:

```
$(function(){ 
    var ms = $(document).height() - $(window).height();

    $(window).scroll(function(){

       var percent = Math.round($(window).scrollTop() / ms * 100); 
    });
});
```

demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/Z6bxD/