# How to animate image on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, i am trying to do an animation on my image in html/css. The problem is, it triggers when i load the page, but i want it to trigger when i **scroll** **down** to the image.

Here is my **HTML** part:

```
<figure>
   <img src="Assets/Images/klenet.jpg" id="clenet_picture">  
   <figcaption id="clenet_text">Clenet Series 1 от 1979 година.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Here is the **CSS** part:

```
#clenet_picture
{
   . . .

   animation-name: image-anim;
   animation-duration: 4s;
}
@keyframes image-anim
{
   from {opacity: 0%}
   to {opacity: 100%}
}
```

I know i need to use some **JS** to make it work, but how exactly do i do that?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62051998/11171286

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Animate image on scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961480/animate-image-on-scroll)

Answer (score 1):

Add another class to it using JS. For example `animate`

Then you can use `#clenet_picture.animate` instead of `#clenet_picture` and animation will only start when you have applied new class

How to check if image is in viewport: [How can I tell if a DOM element is visible in the current viewport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-can-i-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport#answer-7557433)

Comment: Also for such dimple animation I'd suggest you to use transition instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions

Comment: Thanks, but how can i make it to trigger when i scroll down to the picture (my picture is down in my site)?

Comment: @AlexanderSvilarov Added to answer

Answer (score 0):

I think i found a very simple solution.

However, there is one stupid problem.

Here is the code:

```
const checkpoint = 750;

        window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
            
            const currentScroll = window.pageYOffset;
            
            if (currentScroll <= checkpoint) {
                opacity = 1 - currentScroll / checkpoint;
            } else {
                opacity = 0;
            }
            
            document.querySelector(".toAnimate").style.opacity = opacity;
        });
```

The problem is that now it is doing the opposite... When i scroll to the picture, its opacity becomes 0 and when i scroll outside it, it becomes 1...

If someone has a solution, i will be thankful.

And thanks to all answers!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it!

Here is the working code:

```
//The checkpoint is set by you!
const checkpoint = 550;

        window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
            
            const currentScroll = window.pageYOffset;
            
            if (currentScroll <= checkpoint) {
                opacity = 0 + currentScroll / checkpoint;
            } else {
                opacity = 1;
            }
            
            document.querySelector(".toAnimate").style.opacity = opacity;
        });
```

This is the most simple solution, works without CSS!